# Mapear Entidade dinamicamente com ModelMapper, mantendo valores dos atributos nao mapeados da entidade modelo

Tags: java, spring-boot

Estou com problemas para mapear minhas entidades, chegou um ponto da aplicação que eu preciso que que o meu mapeamento tenha um comportamento específico, no caso , tenho um RequestDTO com apenas alguns atributos do meu Modelo, e **preciso que os atributos que não existam no RequestDTO e existam no Modelo tenham os valores do Modelo mantidos**, e não setados como nulo como o ModelMapper faz, como faço para configurar isso?

segue as minhas entidades:
**RequestDTO**

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class RequestDTO {

    @JsonProperty("devedor")
    private String devedor;

    @JsonProperty("cnj")
    private String cnj;

    @JsonProperty("comarca")
    private String comarca;

    @JsonProperty("tipo")
    private String tipo;

    
}
```

**EntidadeFinal** -> cuja a qual eu preciso manter os valores dos campos que não existem no requestDTO quando eu fizer a conversão

```
@EqualsAndHashCode(onlyExplicitlyIncluded = true)
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@SQLRestriction("delete_at IS NULL")
@Table(name = "entidade_final")
public class EntidadeFinal {

    @EqualsAndHashCode.Include
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "devedor")
    private String devedor;

    @Column(name = "cnj")
    private String cnj;

    @Column(name = "comarca")
    private String comarca;

    @Column(name = "data_deposito")
    private Date dataDeposito;

    @Column(name = "conta_deposito_opv")
    private String contaDepositoOpv;

    @Column(name = "tipo")
    private String tipo;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "processo_id")
    private Processo processo;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "credor_primario_id")
    private Credor credorPrimario;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "credor_secundario_id")
    private Credor credorSecundario;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "comprovante_resgate_id")
    private ComprovanteResgate comprovanteResgate;

    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    private OffsetDateTime createdAt;

    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    private OffsetDateTime updatedAt;

    @Column(name = "delete_at")
    private OffsetDateTime deleteAt;

}
```

**Metodo que faz a conversao**

```
public EntidadeFinal toEntity(RequestDTO requestDTO) {
        return this.modelMapper.map(requestDTO, EntidadeFinal.class);
}
```

Comment: Acredito que você precise mudar um pouco a forma como está fazendo o fluxo hoje.
Se você precisa sair de um `RequestDTO` e persistir no banco uma  `EntidadeFinal` você precisa recuperar antes esta instancia de EntidadeFinal, fazer as alterações necessárias e depois mandar persistir.